# HTML big whitespace

Tags: html, whitespace

I'm fairly new here so apologies if this has already been answered somewhere else, I can't seem to find anything about this specific issue though.

I've been struggling to get rid of a huge whitespace that appears next to each webpage I create that is almost the same size as the webpage. It doesn't extend below the page or have any affect on positioning of objects no the page; when I center things they go where I want them to.

[image: Edge of my desired webpage (the blue banners) then the whitespace I can't seem to get rid of]

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        color: #013A51 !important;
     }

    div.a {
       position: relative;
       top:-30px;
    }

    div.c {
       position: relative;
       left: 1000px;
       top: -120px;
    }

    div.b {
       position: relative;
       top: -60px;
    }

    .header {
        padding: 5px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90px;
        text-align: left;
        background: #C5E8F6;
      }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="a">
      <p style="font-size:36px"><b style="color: rgb(0, 229, 158)">Some</b>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      <p style="font-size:15px">Some | <b>Text</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <p style="font-size:15px">SomeText</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us a print screen so we can understand better what is your issue ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: insert your code, pls

Comment: add a screenshot and some code and we will figure out.

Comment: Added a screenshot, I have the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> in the head

Comment: That will not cause that problem. You need to provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: @Hawk10798 paste the code in your answer too see what you do wrong.

Comment: I would suggest you to use the HTML's margin properties to set what you need. But to easy the work, I would suggest using the Bootstrap 4 Grid system as discussed at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Added code. I have used margin properties to the best of my knowledge

Comment: Apologies, just found info on the width property that sorted it swiftly.